# flutter The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>' error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

everyone, i am having issue trying to rendered the selected icon from the list,
bellow is my code.
the iconlist contains the list of all icons

```
  List<Widget> selectedIcon = []; //updated

  List<IconData> iconList = [
    Icons.cake,
    Icons.add_location_sharp,
    Icons.zoom_in_outlined,
    Icons.auto_awesome_motion,
    Icons.call_end_sharp,
    Icons.equalizer_rounded,
    Icons.wifi_lock,
    Icons.mail,
  ];
```

i mapped through the iconlist and add the selected icon to the selectedIcon array,
so, how can i display the selected icon? .thanks

i tried Icon(selectedIcon), but returns the above error

```
 Wrap(
      children: iconList.map((icon) {
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (selectedIcon.contains(icon)) {
                selectedIcon.remove(icon);
              } else {
                selectedIcon.add(icon);
                print(selectedIcon);
              }
            },
            child: Icon(icon));
      }).toList(),
    );
```

Comment: This `var selectedIcon = [];` is inferred as a `List<dynamic>` because there is no way for it to determine what type of elements you want in your list. Instead declare it like `List<Widget> selectedIcon = [];` or `var  selectedIcon = <Widget>[];`

Comment: thanks man, i tried List<Widget> selectedIcon = [];, and now the line " selectedIcon.add(icon);" returns error of "The argument type 'IconData' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget"

Comment: Maybe it should be a `List<IconData>` then. I think we might be missing some context here about how you are displaying the selectedIcon data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding `IconData` but while the list is declared as  `List<Widget>`, it expects to have `Widget` instead `IconData`.

You can replace `List<Widget> selectedIcon` with  `List<IconData> selectedIcon`.

Or  while adding items, use  `selectedIcon.add(Icon(icon));`

You can map your `selectedIcon` the way did for `iconList`.

```dart
 List<IconData> selectedIcon = [];
 
...
///show selected icons
Wrap(
  children: selectedIcon.map((icon) {
    return Icon(icon);
  }).toList(),
),
Wrap(
  children: iconList.map((icon) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (selectedIcon.contains(icon)) {
          selectedIcon.remove(icon);
        } else {
          selectedIcon.add(icon);
        }

        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Icon(icon),
    );
  }).toList(),
),
```

To show only selected Icon, you can use nullable data.

```dart
IconData? selectedIcon;

//....
if (selectedIcon != null) Icon(selectedIcon),
Wrap(
  children: iconList.map((icon) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedIcon = icon;
        });
      },
      child: Icon(icon),
    );
  }).toList(),
),
```

Comment: thanks @Yeasin, this works fine, but i think my logic is wrong, i only want to display just a single icon at a time, that is, only the click icon. please is there a way i can achieve that? thanks

Comment: yap , check the update answer

Comment: thanks, please i am bit confused now, i replaced the second answer with the updated one but i got error on line "    selectedIcon = icon;"  "A value of type 'IconData' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<IconData>'."

Comment: On second answer, I am using single `IconData? selectedIcon;` , you can find it on top line.

Comment: Thanks alot man. i got it right now, i am so grateful